# What is the "value of an argument of a function" called?

Tags: functions, convention

I'm a programmer and therefore used to the differentiate between *parameters* and *arguments*. For programmers, parameters are placeholder variables used to store the inputs of functions; arguments are the concrete values passed to a function application.
**Example:** In the program …

```
let f(x,y) := ...;
let z := 3;
let z := f(1+2, z);
```

… function `f` has the parameters `x` and `y`. The concrete values `1+2` and `z` (that is `3`) are arguments of `f`.

However, in math it seems like *argument* is used to describe any free variable of a function (see *****), not the value given to that variable during an application of that function. That is, the function $g:(u, v)\to\ldots$  has the arguments $u$ and $v$.

When applying $g$, how would I refer to the things $g$ is applied to? That is, **in the application $g(1+2, w)$ what is the name of $1+2$ and $w$ or the tuple $(1+2,w)$?**

---

***** From Wikipedia »[Argument of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function)« (2019-09-16)

> an argument of a function [...] is also called an independent variable.
>   [...] For example, the binary function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ has two arguments, $x$ and $y$.

However, the same article also says

> an argument of a function is a **specific input** to the function

but this definition contradicts the definition as an »*independent variable*«. I ignored the second quote as the rest of the article was just about the first quote.

Comment: The standard terminology is not so "clean" : the [argument of a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_of_a_function) "is a specific input to the function; it is also called an independent variable". We may say that a function has $n$ *argument places* (abbreviated : arguments) : when we assign specific (input) values to the arguments, we can compute the (output) value of the function.

Comment: See [Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) for a clean theory.

Comment: To begin with, you're looking at Wikipedia, written and potentially rewritten over time by many editors of varying types of competence. I generally would not rely on it to use exactly the right word in exactly the right way every time. It is possible that the "specific" input means which of the multiple inputs in the case of a multiple-parameter function. That is, in $f(x,y)$, the variable $x$ represents specifically the first parameter.

Comment: As for the main question, the answer may be in the title: "value of an argument." We don't always make a one-word synonym for a useful noun phrase when the noun phrase is that short.

Comment: Thank you for the replies so far Mauro and David. Both of you have helped me a bit. However, it's a pity that there doesn't seem to be a standard terminology.

Comment: There can’t be a special word for every particular thing. I think that natural language serves us pretty well: of the many ways of expressing what you want, “the value associated to the argument(s)” is only one.